# Goto user/index if user is logged in & he hit user/login URL

Tags: php, cakephp, authorization, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

Hello i am using Auth component for Authentication only(Which pages to be given access to which users). I did Login myself using MD5 password .

The problem is When i hit usrs/login URL , it still shows login screen Even If i am logged in.What should be done for that .I tried following ,but didnt work.

```
//In User controller 

function beforeFilter()
{

    //Here set Which pages should be accessable to various users
    $adminPages =array('index','logout','changeProfPic','add','edit','delete','resetpwd','updatepwd');
    $allUsersPages = array('login','forgot','resetpwd','updatepwd','index','logout');
    $withoutLoginPages = array('login','forgot','resetpwd');

    //Pages for owner only
    if($this->Session->check('userID') && ($this->Session->read('role')== SUPER_ADMIN || $this->Session->read('role')== ADMIN))
    {
        $this->Auth->allow($adminPages);
    }
    else if($this->Session->check('userID') && ($this->Session->read('role')== STAFF || $this->Session->read('role')== USER))
    {
         $this->Auth->allow($allUsersPages);
    }
    else
    {
         $this->Auth->allow($withoutLoginPages);
    }
//For all the users

}
```

// In same controller Login func.

```
function login($id=null)
{
    //If form is posted
    if(!empty($this->data))
    {
        //$hashedPassword=Security::hash($this->data['User']['password'],NULL,TRUE); //Hash password
        $hashedPassword= md5($this->data['User']['password']); //Hash password

        $conditionsLogIn = array(
            'user_name' => trim($this->data['User']['username']),
            'password' => $hashedPassword
        );

        $userDetails=$this->User->find('first',array('conditions'=>$conditionsLogIn));

        if($userDetails)
        {
            $this->Session->write('fname',$userDetails['User']['first_name']);
            $this->Session->write('lname',$userDetails['User']['last_name']);
            $this->Session->write('role',$userDetails['User']['user_type_id']);
            $this->Session->write('userID',$userDetails['User']['id']);
            $this->Session->write('userType',$userDetails['UserType']['name']);             

            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'index'));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Incorrect Username or Password.','default', array ('class' => 'msgflashError'),'invalidFlag1');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is code in index action ?

Comment: Why don't you use the core authentication mechanism ? Using plain md5 to store passwords is really less secure than what comes out of the box with Cake as it is subject to rainbow tables attack.

Comment: I am doing Front end using PhoneGap ,Not all is cakePHP.So webservices are in Core PHP .Thus md5() pwd is done myself.I know ur concern but issue is solved look below

Answer (score 0):

I got solution : I commented All `App-controller` .And added following code in login method

```
function login($id=null)
{

    if($this->Session->check('userID')) 
    {
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'index'));
    }
```

.....Other code